# Disable keyboard shortcut when Colorbox Event is fired and then Restore it when another Event fires?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox, keyboard-events

I am using the jQuery Colorbox library which is a library of creating Modals that can load images and other content in a nice popup modal window.

I am using it on my portfolio/projects page to allow clicking on a screenshot image and it will load a larger view of the image into a popup modal window.  When opened in the Colorbox modal, I can use my keyboards `LEFT` and `RIGHT` keys to navigate between all my images that have colorbox attachedon the page.

My issue is that I also have some JavaScript setup on my project page to allow the user to use `LEFT` and `RIGHT` arrow keys to navigate to the Next and Previous project page.

So when viewing a Project page, left and right arrow keys works perfectly to loads and browse through my whole portfolio.  As soon as I click on an image which loads in a Colorbox modal window.  I run into my issue!

Now my arrow keys for Project navigation continue to work but my Colorbox key navigation does not work.

Colorbox fires off some `EVENTS` when a modal is opened and closed though.

---

**So I am hoping that when a modal is opened, I can disable my Projects keyboard navigation.**

**When that same Modal is closed, I can restore the keyboard navigation functionality back to my Projects!**

**The problem is I do not know how to do this and need some help please!?**

I have useful code snippets below...

As well as the Documentation site for the jQuery Colorbox Modal library here http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

**This is the code that handles my Project keyboard navigation.**

```
  // Handle Right and Left Keyboard Arrow presses to navigate to Next or Previous Project
  $("body").keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which === 37) { // left
      $("#page-left").parent("a")[0].click();
    }
    else if(e.which === 39) { // right
      $("#page-right").parent("a")[0].click();
    }
  });
```

**This is the code that handles my Colorbox initiation.**

```
  // Setup my Colorbox modal for project images
  $(".projectFUllModal").colorbox({
    rel:'projectFUllModal',
    transition:"none",
    width:"90%",
    height:"90%"
  });
```

**This code below is example code from the Colorbox docs for how to use the Events it can fire off.**

```
  // Colorbox Event for Opening a Modal
  $(document).bind('cbox_open', function(){
    // Disable my Project keyboard navigation functionality
  });

  // Colorbox Event for Closing a Modal
  $(document).bind('cbox_closed', function(){
    // Restore my Project keyboard navigation functionality
  });
```

**Available Colorbox Events**

```
  cbox_open triggers when Colorbox is first opened, but after a few key variable assignments take place.
  cbox_load triggers at the start of the phase where content type is determined and loaded.
  cbox_complete triggers when the transition has completed and the newly loaded content has been revealed.
  cbox_cleanup  triggers as the close method begins.
  cbox_closed triggers as the close method ends.
```

Comment: Don't worry, most users won't even know you can browse using the arrow keys, it's not that common on the web, most people use cursor-based navigation.

Comment: @Nit I agree with you however I would like to figure out how to resolve this either way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should actually be pretty easy to fix, via adding a boolean var:

```
// Handle Right and Left Keyboard Arrow presses to navigate to Next or Previous Project
var canUseArrows = true;
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which === 37 && canUseArrows) { // left
        $("#page-left").parent("a")[0].click();
    }
    else if(e.which === 39 && canUseArrows) { // right
        $("#page-right").parent("a")[0].click();
    }
});
```

And the functions would simply be changed to:

```
// Colorbox Event for Opening a Modal
$(document).bind('cbox_open', function(){
    canUseArrows = false;
});

// Colorbox Event for Closing a Modal
$(document).bind('cbox_closed', function(){
    canUseArrows = true;
});
```

[Here's a fiddle showing it working, with checkbox checked simulating a cbox being open.](http://jsfiddle.net/Oceanity/tm4k69rb/)

Comment: Hey thanks, I was definitely over-thinking this one!  Was also working on setting up a fiddle with colorbox and my code for a real test but you beat me to it so I will instead try this out on my project and report back with how it went, thanks I appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem, it happens to the best of us!  I've gotten into the habit of throwing booleans on any and all kinds of user input after my time messing around in Unity; there are just too many instances when dealing with user-interaction where you don't want the user to have access to controls, so adding that extra manual lock-out is perfect.

Comment: Just implemented this in and it works perfectly!  I had hoped it would be this simple but just didn't know what was going to be involved at first.   My portfolio is coming along nicely with a mixture of JS libraries.  I have it set to open a screenshot image in the colorbox modal when clicked on but also have a Zoom plugin so when you simply hover over the image it zooms in on it, then clicking launches the large image in modal.  It might be overkill but it actually turned out pretty nice.  I have been a backend dev for 14 years and just more focussed on learning JS in the last couple...

Comment: I have to say that working with JS seems more rewarding as far as developing cool features and functionality.  Amazing what can be done with it now days!

Comment: The funny things is I started out as a hobby C# dev with little to no web development experience and I was always under the impression javascript would never be viable for anything more than simple functions and calculations, then irony struck and I got a full-time position as a web developer and I've since come to respect the little scripting language as an invaluable tool.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure when this was added, but now you can use the `arrowKey` option to disable the arrow keys navigation in colorbox.